# Create and save new file in Blob Storage in each pipeline run

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to create a *csv* file in blob storage for each run of a pipeline in Azure Data Factory with a custom name?

Each *csv* has to have the date of the run (which I can easily set with a variable) in its name as it has data related to that date.

I don't have any idea how to do that since the sink property in the "Copy" activity allows to select an already created "Sink dataset" but not to create a new one in each pipeline run.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have any idea how to do that since the sink property in the
>   "Copy" activity allows to select an already created "Sink dataset" but
>   not to create a new one in each pipeline run.

Yes,the source and sink dataset should be specific exactly.You can't set dynamic sink dataset when you execute copy activity.

According to your description,you want to log the execution date of every ADF pipeline into different files separately.Per my knowledge,no direct option to implement that.Provide below possible workaround for your reference:

Enable diagnostic logs with your ADF account and set the residence(Blob Storage) of log files. You could view the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#schema-of-logs-and-events) in that log file:`pipelineName ,start,end`.

Use Azure Function Blob Trigger to get the entire data from the file.And create the files separately as you want into another blob storage path with code.

Comment: Thank you so much!, the problem is that in those files I need to actually copy the data (table) that I am generating in the pipeline and save it in a blob storage.(with the custom name with execution date)

Comment: @JavierSantiagoCáceres I'm confused. You want to save the actual data or save the execution log of pipeline/

Comment: @JavierSantiagoCáceres Based on your description in above question,you already have work pipelines and you just want to log the run logs of pipeline into blob storage.